# How to setup NIC bonding in Ubuntu 20.04 docker image

Tags: networking, docker, network-bonding, nic

I want to sent ip NIC bonding (teaming) in Ubuntu 20.04 eve-ng docker image. when i enter command "sudo mobprobe bonding" I receive the following error;

modprobe: FATAL: Module bonding not found in directory /lib/modules/5.17.8-eve-ng-uksm-wg+

can anyone help me to setup the NIC bonding on my Ubuntu container running in EVE-NG?

Many Regards